# In sale or custom made?

Tags: connector, identification, network, board, rj45

[image]
[image]

RJ45 to 8 pos board connector. 
Board connector width: 12,4 mm
Pin pitch: 2 mm

Found inside a plastic card printer. 
Somewhere to purchase cable? 
Identification of the board connector?

Comment: I see the question was down-voted and also there are currently three votes to close. But isn't this at least a valid component ID question? Please consider if maybe we are being too rash to close and downvote this question.

Comment: Custom but relatively easy to reproduce if you can identify a near enough (6 not 8 way) JST conn.

Comment: if you can produce set of higher resolution pictures from all faces of this connector, maybe someone can identify the manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

the board connector looks like JST PH series

The rest of the  cable looks like half of a T568B CAT5 patch calble

the presence of un-used conductors in the cable makes this almost certainnly custom.  someone has cut a patch cable in half and connected five of the conductors  to the JST connector, trimmed the others back and put heat-shrink over that.